# terraform input selection based on condition under resource inputs

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, terraform, devops, hcl

I need to select the block of content based on condition to use under resource inputs,

if var.enable_auto_scaling == false, use below inputs

```
    node_count            = 1
```

if var.enable_auto_scaling == true, use below inputs

```
  max_count = 8
  min_count = 1
```

code:

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool" "example" {
  name                  = "internal"
  kubernetes_cluster_id = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.id
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS2_v2"

  # if var.enable_auto_scaling == false
  #     node_count            = 1       
  # if var.enable_auto_scaling == true
  #     max_count = 8
  #     min_count = 1

  tags = {
    Environment = "Production"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [conditional expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/conditionals.html):

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool" "example" {
  name                  = "internal"
  kubernetes_cluster_id = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.id
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS2_v2"

  node_count            = var.enable_auto_scaling == false ? 1 : null    

  enable_auto_scaling   = var.enable_auto_scaling
  max_count = 8         = var.enable_auto_scaling == true ? 8 : null    
  min_count = 1         = var.enable_auto_scaling == true ? 1 : null    

  tags = {
    Environment = "Production"
  }
}
```